How do you dynamically add multiple options to a sqlalchemy 2.0 select query
I'm trying to build a dynamic query in Async Sqlalchemy 2.0.  The options come in as a list like:
select_options=[selectinload(Table.entitity1).selectinload(Table2.entity2)]

And then I do this:
query = select(model).filter(model.id == item_id).options(select_options[0])
result = await async_session.execute(query)

That works great and I get the correct response.  But I want to be able to keep appending options to that statement.  I tried this as an example and figured if this worked I could then just loop through select_options and add each one:
query = select(model)
query.filter(model.id == item_id)
query.options(select_options[0])

I didn't get any errors, but the response ignored the options. How can I keep adding on .options().options(), etc.?
Thanks

This should work, filter and options return a new select.
query = select(model)
query = query.filter(model.id == item_id)
query = query.options(select_options[0])

When you get a lot of things though it can be easier to build them up separately and build the select at the end.
and_args = []
if check_flags:
    and_args.append(or_(model.flag1 == True, model.flag2 == False))
if only_roots:
    and_args.append(model.parent_id == None)

query = select(model).filter(*and_args)


Thanks Ian.  Let me try that and see if that works for me.  My current work around is just an if statement of select statements based on the array length. But this would be much cleaner.

That did the trick and solved my issue.  Thanks so much for the help
